# ListView item not getting removed in BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview

I have an `expandablelistView`. When the list is clicked, it will display two buttons. When delete button is clicked, it suppose to remove the child and parent item. Unfortunately, nothing is removed.

```
 ArrayList<ListObj> groupList= new ArrayList<ListObj>();
     listview = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exlistView);
     expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(AddMonthlyExpenses.this,getApplication(), groupList);
     listview.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
     retrieveList(name);

public void retrieveList(String name) {
        groupList.clear();
        database = mdb.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE__TASK + " WHERE Name = ? ", new String[]{name}, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            groupList = new ArrayList<ListObj>();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int iD = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                String month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Month"));
                double budget = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Budget"));
                groupList.add(new ListObj(iD,month,budget));
                if (expListAdapter != null) {
                    expListAdapter.add(iD, month, budget,"edit");
                   listview.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Adapter class**

```
 public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ListObj> laptops;
    Activity parentActivity;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    MyDatabaseHelper mdb;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity parentActivity, Context context, ArrayList<ListObj> laptops) {
        this.parentActivity= parentActivity;
        this.context = context;
        this.laptops = laptops;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mdb= new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<ItemDetails> productList =
                laptops.get(groupPosition).getProductList();
        return productList.get(childPosition);
    }


    public void add(int id, String month, double budget) {
        String[] splited = month.split("\\s+");
        ListObj obj = new ListObj(id, month, budget);
        obj.setYear(splited[1]);
        obj.setMonth(splited[0]);
        obj.setBudget(budget);
        obj.setID(id);
//        mySection.put(obj);
        laptops.add(obj);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ArrayList<ItemDetails> productList = obj.getProductList();

        ItemDetails detailInfo = new ItemDetails();
        productList.add(detailInfo);
        obj.setProductList(productList);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return laptops.size();
    }

    public void removeItem(long position) {
        laptops.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public ListObj getItem(int position) {
        return laptops.get(position);
    }

    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        }

        Button editButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        Button deleteButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(parentActivity);
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove?");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
//                                Toast.makeText(context,"button clicked  "+ groupPosition,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                ListObj headerInfo = laptops.get(groupPosition);
                                deleteData(headerInfo.getID());
                                removeItem(groupPosition);
                                Toast.makeText(context,"list deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    public void deleteData(long id)
    {
        database = mdb.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_EXPENSES, MyDatabaseHelper.ID2 + "=?", new String[]{id + ""});
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<ItemDetails>itemDetails=laptops.get(groupPosition).getProductList();
        return itemDetails.size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return laptops.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.laptops.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.expenses_adapter, null);
        TextView month = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textMonth);
        TextView budget = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAmount);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textYear);
        month.setText(laptops.get(groupPosition).getMonth());
        budget.setText(laptops.get(groupPosition).getBudget()+"");
        year.setText(laptops.get(groupPosition).getYear());
        return convertView;
    }


    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My adapter class is extending **BaseExpandableListAdapter**

[image]

Comment: post complete code

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh edited.

Comment: After you remove an item, you can simply clear your adapter and set your list to adapter again.

Comment: try changing `hasStableIds` to `false`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh works like charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First : you need to change `hasStableIds` because the removal and adding operation on list will change the indexes of list so `true` mean , expandable list view can reuse views against corresponding ID's  and it can cause issue of unwanted reuse of dirty(removed) views

```
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}
```

Second : As you mentioned you need to use `int` instead of `long` because  by doing this

```
 laptops.remove(position);
```

the `long` position  will be `AutoBoxed` into `Long` so it will invoke the overridden version of `remove` which take `Object` i.e  [`ArrayList#remove(Object)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) which result into

```
 laptops.remove(LongObject);
```

so it will try to search and remove a `Long` object (who's value is the position) from the `ArrayList` though there is no `Long` object present in list.

Why Boxing?

As per the rule of

[Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

> int will be promoted to long but inverse is not automatically allowed (result in lost of data)

so `long` will be `boxed` to `Long` to invoke the more specific remove method `ArrayList#remove(Object)`

Solution : with use `int` or apply casting to `int` while using `remove` as

```
 laptops.remove((int)position);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir.!

Comment: @JohnJoe because compiler sees that there is a version of `remove` method available which can take an Object so it will go smart and convert `long` to `Long` but unfortunately we don't want it (don't want to remove item by matching object but we want to remove item by position ) and i am glad that i could help

Answer (score 1):

After I change the `long` to `int` and set `hasStableIds` to false, it works like charm.

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
        laptops.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I was passing the wrong datatype. But strange, I not received any errors.

Comment: To understand the behavior , you can check my answer below although it is happening due to `AutoBoxing`